# How do i make a 3d game pixel perfect? so that there is no anti aliasing or other filtering applied

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is what the game looks like in the 'game' window in unity, which is what it should look like https://ibb.co/xjst4vw achieved by removing all lighting including ambient lighting.

And this is what it looks once built https://ibb.co/4RcbMv8

Why is there a haze in the border between colors? How do I get it to be pixel perfect?

The aspect ratio of the in editor display is 160x144

I have change the game resolution by going to >edit >project setting >player and changing the height and width to the right size

The camera is also passing to a render texture which is of the right size, with the filter mode set to point.

I cant figure out what is causing this. to my knowledge All lighting is turned off. It looks like some up scaling error or maybe some sort of anti-aliasing effect which has also been turned off everywhere i could find.

Does anyone have an idea about what might be causing this? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question the resolution in the >edit >project setting >player >resolution and presentation need to be as high res as it can be so in my case for a 1920x1080 screen it should 1120,1008 which is 160x144 scaled up by 7.

Then send data from you're main camera to a render texture that is set to the resolution you want (in my case 160x144) and create UI canvas that takes up the whole screen and a raw image as a child. Then put the render texture you created in the texture.

Answer (score 0):

There is postprocessing window in unity where you can specify such things like antyaliasing and so on. I think that this will make your game pixel perfect.